# buildTokenWithUid Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, video, broadcast

I am trying to set up user accounts using Unity.

I am unable to locate the method "buildTokenWithUid". Which API call should I make or which class this method "buildTokenWithUid" belongs to?

I have successfully registered user account, I have a channel name, I just need the token hence wanted to use "buildTokenWithUid".

Please can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API. Where did you find it from?
Token related information can be found in [FAQ](https://docs.agora.io/en/faqs/token_usage_generation_description#generate-and-use-a-token).